# Converting button values to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm building a web app with node.js and mongodb.

So my app has table which for loops different info to the table from the database.

I have a delete function which I built following [this tutorial](https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-and-mongodb-2/) and I have a problem with it.

So here's my js code for the onclick function.

```
function myFunction() {

    fetch('guests', {
        method: 'delete',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'guestnumber': '3'
        })
    })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.ok) return res.json();
        }).
        then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            window.location.reload();
        });
}
```

Now the this code works just fine but it will only delete the table `<td>` with the guestnumber 3. My every button looks like this = `<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="myFunction()" data-value="<% guests[i].guestnumber %>"` (Note. this is an EJS page.)

Is there a way to get the data-values of my buttons to the fetch's body part so that every button would use the data-value in the onclick function?

Answer (score 0):

You weren't passing a value to your function as an argument so you're app wasn't dynamic, just static info.

Make guestnumber equal to your argument.

```
function myFunction(id) {

    fetch('guests', {
        method: 'delete',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: { guestnumber: id }
    })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.ok) return res.json();
        }).
        then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            window.location.reload();
        });
}
```

Then in your HTML put the ejs inside the onclick function as well to pass it to myFunction. Like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="myFunction('<% guests[i].guestnumber %>')" data-value="<% guests[i].guestnumber %>"
```

Comment: You're welcome! Upvoting the answer and confirm it as correct is the best way to show appreciation and it allows others to find this answer faster!